# помогите перейти к графическому интерфейсу

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui

всем привет, есть задача - создать алгоритм решения линейных неравенств с одной переменной на питоне и сделать его визуализацию с помощью посторонних библиотек, типо tkinter, никогда не делал ничего подобного, возможно, кто-то может помочь мне с этим?
на выводе желательно видеть ответ, чем может быть x, и координатную прямую, где как-то показано, например, другим цветом или штрихом доступную область значений x
нужно создать прямую и чтобы на ней отмечался отрезок со значениями, которые допускает неравенство. плюсом нужно ещё как-то подать это в виде как для -2x =< 5 вывести x есть [-2,5 ; +∞) и чтобы такие ответы были на каждый запрос, от пользователя должно приниматься значения k и b - некие числа, а программа должна всё посчитать и выдать результат, о котором говорилось выше, вот алгоритм для терминала:

```
def main():
print("Введите числа k и b: ", end="")
k, b = map(float, input().split())
print("Введите знак неравенства: ", end="")
zn = str(input())

if k == 0:
    if zn == '<=' or zn == '<':
        print('x - любое число')
    else:
        print('x - любое число')
else:
    prb = b/k

    if b < 0 or k < 0:
        if zn == '>':
            zn = '<'
        elif zn == '<':
            zn = '>'
        elif zn == '>=':
            zn = '<='
        elif zn == '<=':
            zn = '>='

    print('Ответ: ', end="")
    if zn == '>=':
        print(f'x есть [{prb} ; +inf)')
    elif zn == '>':
        print(f'x есть ({prb} ; +inf)')
    elif zn == '<=':
        print(f'x есть (-inf ; {prb}]')
    elif zn == '<':
        print(f'x есть (-inf ; {prb})')


main()
```

Comment: И в чём затруднения? Не знаешь Питон? Не можешь сформулировать алгоритм решения неравенства? Не можешь нарисовать картинку на Питоне? Или всё вместе? Я тоже не могу рисовать на Питоне. Но могу за 15 минут найти, как это сделать.

Comment: скажем так, алгоритм я бы смог сделать сам, но как его визуализировать с помощью какого-то там tkinter или чего подобного на координатной прямой не понимаю, нужно создать саму прямую и чтобы на прямой отмечался отрезок со значениями, которые допускает неравенство. плюсом нужно ещё как-то подать это в нише алгебры, типо как для x ∈ ℝ в неравенстве нужно сделать x∈(−∞,+∞) и что бы такие отвтеы были на каждый запрос, типо от пользователя должно приниматься значения k и b - некие числа, а программа должна всё посчитать и выдать результат, о котором говорилось выше

Comment: Ок. Давай напиши для начала программу с консольным интерфейсом. То есть ввод двух чисел, знака неравенства, решение и вывод результата. А потом уже будем переводить ответ в графику.

Comment: готово, накидал немного алгоритма, может у тебя есть телеграм, я код скину?

Comment: Не, не, я не персональный консультант. Вставь код в свой вопрос. А сам вопрос я бы сформулировал так: "Помогите перейти к графическому интерфейсу". И обязательно написать, как ты умудрился не найти ответ на этот вопрос в Интернете.

Comment: да я сразу полез сюда, сорри, всё исправил, надеюсь, теперь на мой вопрос смогут ответить

Comment: Супер. Я пока отвлекусь, а ты поищи. Может, и народ подтянется.

Comment: окей, сейчас поищу, удачи там

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуй так:

```
import tkinter as tk
# Если появляется ошибка AttributeError: module 'backend_interagg' has no attribute 'FigureCanvas',
# можно попробовать использовать следующие строки:
# import matplotlib
# matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def main(k, b, zn):
    if k == 0:
        if zn in ('<=', '<'):
            return 'x есть (-∞ ; +∞)'
        else:
            return 'x - любое число'
    else:
        prb = b / k

        if b < 0 or k < 0:
            if zn == '>':
                zn = '<'
            elif zn == '<':
                zn = '>'
            elif zn == '>=':
                zn = '<='
            elif zn == '<=':
                zn = '>='

        if zn == '>=':
            return f'x есть [{prb} ; +∞)'
        elif zn == '>':
            return f'x есть ({prb} ; +∞)'
        elif zn == '<=':
            return f'x есть (-∞ ; {prb}]'
        elif zn == '<':
            return f'x есть (-∞ ; {prb})'

def calculate():
    # Функция для расчетов и построения графиков.
    k = float(k_entry.get())  # Получаем значение k из текстового поля и преобразуем его в число.
    b = float(b_entry.get())  # Получаем значение b из текстового поля и преобразуем его в число.
    zn = zn_entry.get()  # Получаем значение знака неравенства.

    result = main(k, b, zn)  # Вызываем функцию для решения неравенства.
    result_label.config(text=result)  # Обновляем текст результата.

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()  # Создаем новый график.
    x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 400)  # Генерируем 400 равномерно распределенных значений от -10 до 10.
    y = [k * xi + b if k * xi + b >= 0 else np.nan for xi in x]  # Создаем массив y в соответствии с условиями.
    ax.plot(x, y, label=f'y = {k}x + {b}')  # Строим график.
    ax.axhline(0, color='black', linewidth=0.5)  # Добавляем горизонтальную ось.
    ax.axvline(0, color='black', linewidth=0.5)  # Добавляем вертикальную ось.
    ax.legend()  # Добавляем легенду.

    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=window)  # Создаем объект "полотно" для Tkinter.
    canvas_widget = canvas.get_tk_widget()  # Получаем виджет для встраивания.
    canvas_widget.grid(row=4, columnspan=3)  # Размещаем виджет на форме.

window = tk.Tk()  # Создаем основное окно приложения.
window.title("Решение линейных неравенств")  # Устанавливаем заголовок окна.

k_label = tk.Label(window, text="k:")  # Создаем надпись "k:".
k_label.grid(row=0, column=0)  # Размещаем надпись на форме.
k_entry = tk.Entry(window)  # Создаем поле для ввода k.
k_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)  # Размещаем поле для ввода на форме.

b_label = tk.Label(window, text="b:")  # Создаем надпись "b:".
b_label.grid(row=1, column=0)  # Размещаем надпись на форме.
b_entry = tk.Entry(window)  # Создаем поле для ввода b.
b_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)  # Размещаем поле для ввода на форме.

zn_label = tk.Label(window, text="Знак неравенства:")  # Создаем надпись "Знак неравенства:".
zn_label.grid(row=2, column=0)  # Размещаем надпись на форме.
zn_entry = tk.Entry(window)  # Создаем поле для ввода знака неравенства.
zn_entry.grid(row=2, column=1)  # Размещаем поле для ввода на форме.

calculate_button = tk.Button(window, text="Рассчитать", command=calculate)  # Создаем кнопку "Рассчитать".
calculate_button.grid(row=3, columnspan=2)  # Размещаем кнопку на форме.

result_label = tk.Label(window, text="")  # Создаем метку для вывода результата.
result_label.grid(row=3, column=2)  # Размещаем метку на форме.

window.mainloop()  # Запускаем главный цикл обработки событий.
```

Comment: двигаешься в правильном направлении, только мне нужен не график, а чисто прямая, типо как тут: https://ibb.co/7JLb63V